# Excel: Conditional formatting for subtotals

Tags: excel

Whenever I auto-generate subtotals in Excel, only the "subtotal" label is added in bold, not the result. I'd like to have the complete "subtotal" row in bold.

I'd tried the tutorial [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-bold-subtotals.htm) but for some reason I cannot get the formula to work at all, i.e. nothing happens. I tried some other formulas myself but not even the simplest ones are working.

What formula should I use in conditional formatting to get the complete subtotal row in bold whenever it's added? I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: Can you show us what exactly did you try? That tutorial tells you exactly on how it is done and it is correct.

Comment: yep - a screenshot with a copy of last attempted formula will help a lot

Comment: Thanks for your replies, see my answer (sorry in advance).

Answer (score 0):

Use the USerDefined function isBold described here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/398006-checking-whether-a-field-is-bold.html and conditional formatting via formula.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it was a rather simple problem: I used a comma instead of semicolon to seperate the arguments in the formula (I know...). Sorry to have wasted your time on question: a good night of sleep is all that it took :P